# Persistent Application

Tags: c#, process, kill

I'm working on a Parental Control program in Windows that controls websites which a user can access.
The main problem I'm facing is that the "kid" is able to close the application and go anywhere he wants!!!

What is the best way to make it impossible or hard to close an app?
as an Example, closing Anti-Virus applications is very hard.

any help?

Comment: Closing anti-virus applications is hard? More like closing viruses is hard.

Comment: Closing AV applications is often hard because they've slowed the machine to such a crawl that you've forgotten what you were doing before you get to the close button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it as a Windows Service which runs as an account the ordinary user doesn't have access to.

Comment: +1 A service running under the system account cannot be controlled by a non-admin user.  C# has some nice integration with Windows Services so you can respond to start and stop requests gracefully.  See MSDN for details.